# Hide menu-items from navigation using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide some menu from the navigation if the user role is *User* and show all menu to the *Admin*.
I want to hide *User* *SSO Mapping* and *Log* from the user.

I am using the *OpenID Connect flask* for authentication.

Can anyone help me in this?

```
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="dash.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Change Password</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-btn">User
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-container">
                    <a href="#">View Users</a>
                    <a href="#">Add User</a>
                    <a href="#">Manage Role</a>
                  </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Log</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">SSO Mapping</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Login History</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Support Guide</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you describe the specific error you're running into?

Comment: @CameronLittle I tried some scripting codes but it didn't work. It didn't hide or show anything. It hides total nav bar

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use a server-side templating engine to do that. (or maybe a UI framework like React and Vue).

But since you are using HTML here,

**With a server-side templating engine.**

You can store a cookie that determines the role of the user.
If using Node.js with Express,

```js
req.session.role = "User"; // this will be based on the login
```

Now you can simply use a good templating engine like EJS to render it.

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index.ejs', {
    role: req.session.role
  })
})
```

in your index.ejs,

```html
<% if(role == "Admin") { %>
  <li>
    <a class="dropdown-btn">User
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <a href="#">View Users</a>
      <a href="#">Add User</a>
      <a href="#">Manage Role</a>
    </div>
  </li>
<% } %>
```

NOTE: **Since you have not specified how you the login and role determination works, this is by far the only way of doing *securely***

Comment: I am using the openid connect flask example for login. and I use the scope to retrieve the user role. @divysrivastava